# Aggregating with pd.NamedAgg with additional conditions

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I want to aggregate time-series data based on several conditions.
Apart of grouping the data by a timespan and the "type"- column, I would like to count and sum only positive values in the respective groups.
Can this be done elegantly without using .filter or creating subsets beforehand, and merging the aggregate data after?

*The following code has been corrected thanks to jezrael's answer below. However, you should check out his answer for a more performant solution.*
While I prefer "the style" of the solution that I took here, for my dataframe ~50k rows, his approach is far faster.

Sample data:

```
datelist = ['2021-01-01','2021-02-01','2021-03-01']
datelist = [pd.to_datetime(item) for item in datelist] 
datelist = [item for item in datelist for _ in (range(5))]
valuelist = np.random.randint(-100,100,size=(15))
typelist = np.random.randint(0,3, size=(15))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'values': valuelist,
     'types': typelist
    }, index = datelist)
print(df)
            values  types
2021-01-01     -91      2
2021-01-01     -32      1
2021-01-01     -88      1
2021-01-01       7      1
2021-01-01     -84      0
2021-02-01     -57      0
2021-02-01     -28      1
2021-02-01     -11      0
2021-02-01     -66      1
2021-02-01      -9      2
2021-03-01      55      2
2021-03-01     -10      0
2021-03-01     -89      1
2021-03-01      61      1
2021-03-01     -28      1

myagg = {
        'values_sum' : ('values', 'sum'),
        'values_positive_count' : ('values', lambda x: (x > 0).sum()), # counts positive values
        'values_negative_count' : ('values', lambda x: (x < 0).sum()), # counts negative values
        'values_negative_sum' : ('values', lambda x: ((x < 0)*x).sum()), # corrected the parenthesis thanks to jezraels input - works now
    }
df_agg = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'), pd.Grouper('type')]).agg(**myagg)
```

Desired result:

```
print(dfagg)
                  sum  values_positive_count  values_negative_count  a_positive_sum
           types                                                   
2021-01-01 0      106                      3                      0               0
           1      -62                      0                      1               7
           2       -4                      0                      1               0
2021-02-01 0      -97                      0                      2               0
           1       12                      1                      1               0
           2       58                      1                      0               0
2021-03-01 0      -35                      1                      1               0
           1      111                      2                      0              55
           2       85                      1                      0              61
```

Comment: I'm guessing you know that it is more efficient (i'd even say cleaner/more elegant) to filter first before aggregating

Comment: Since I want the sum of all values and more aggregations that are not based on subsets in the same dataframe, it would be more elegant to do it in one step, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `(` after `lambda x` and for match column `types` is not necessary for `pd.Grouper`:

```
myagg = {
        'values_sum' : ('values', 'sum'),
        'values_positive_count' : ('values', lambda x: (x > 0).sum()), 
        'values_negative_count' : ('values', lambda x: (x < 0).sum()),
        'values_negative_sum' : ('values', lambda x: ((x < 0)*x).sum()), 
}
df_agg = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'), 'types']).agg(**myagg)
```

Or if you need better performance, create helper columns before `groupby` like this, so aggregate by `sum` only:

```
myagg = {
        'values_sum' : ('values', 'sum'),
        'values_positive_count' : ('p', 'sum'),
        'values_negative_count' : ('n', 'sum'),
        'values_negative_sum' : ('n_sum','sum')
}
df_agg = (df.assign(p = df['values'].gt(0),
                    n = df['values'].lt(0),
                    n_sum = df['values'].lt(0).mul(df['values']),
                   )
            .groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'), 'types'])
            .agg(**myagg))
```

Comment: The second solution is better, and should be more performant (my personal opinion)

Comment: @sammywemmy - absolutely agree.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I have chosen your answer, corrected my example code above, and refered to it in the text.

Answer (score 1):

It makes a result what you desired:

#1. **Using 'NamedAgg'** (https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'values': valuelist,
        'types': typelist,
        'date': datelist,  # You do not need to make it as index.
    }
)

df = df.groupby(['date', 'types']).agg(
    sum=pd.NamedAgg(column='values', aggfunc=sum),
    values_positive_count=pd.NamedAgg(column='values', aggfunc=lambda x: (x>0).sum()),
    values_negative_count=pd.NamedAgg(column='values', aggfunc=lambda x: (x<0).sum()),
    a_positive_sum=pd.NamedAgg(column='values', aggfunc=lambda x: ((x > 0)*x).sum()),
)

print(df)
```

#2. **Using groupby and rename**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'values': valuelist,
        'types': typelist,
        'date': datelist,  # You do not need to make it as index.
    }
)

df = df.groupby(['date', 'types']).agg({
    'values': [sum, lambda x: (x>0).sum(), lambda x: (x<0).sum(), lambda x: ((x > 0)*x).sum()]
})

df = df.rename(columns={
    '<lambda_0>': 'values_positive_count',
    '<lambda_1>': 'values_negative_count',
    '<lambda_2>': 'a_positive_sum',
})
df = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)

print(df)
```

```
                  sum  values_positive_count  values_negative_count  a_positive_sum
date       types                                                                   
2021-01-01 0      -69                      0                      1               0
           1       49                      1                      0              49
           2       91                      2                      1             107
2021-02-01 0       -6                      1                      1              93
           1       -1                      1                      1              63
           2       14                      1                      0              14
2021-03-01 0      -67                      0                      2               0
           1       60                      1                      1              90
           2      -93                      0                      1               0
```

Comment: Thanks, this works too- I think jezraels code is a bit leaner and closer to my solution, so I preferred it as an answer. But I appreciate the alternative solution.